# how to show all package dependency tree

Tags: meteor, package

Since 0.9.3 I'm having some problems with meteor package dependencies, for example some third party packages don't declare all of their dependencies (like underscore, which would normally be included but not when used by another package).

Is there a simple way to show the tree of dependencies, much like npm does?

meteor list
will show what's in your project

.meteor/versions  will show all packages
but I'm trying to find out what is including (or not) other packages.

currently I'm getting errors like the following, but haven't included Minimongoid afaik and grepping finds no reference to it.

```
W20141001-19:19:46.137(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.he3qxx++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20141001-19:19:46.137(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20141001-19:19:46.138(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20141001-19:19:46.141(-7)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Minimongoid is not defined
W20141001-19:19:46.141(-7)? (STDERR)     at collections/user.coffee:1:20
W20141001-19:19:46.141(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/dc/dev/shumi/package-dev/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/collections/user.coffee.js:24:3
W20141001-19:19:46.142(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/dc/dev/shumi/package-dev/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141001-19:19:46.142(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141001-19:19:46.142(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.he3qxx++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141001-19:19:46.142(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/dc/dev/shumi/package-dev/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
```

Comment: I'd also like to be able to do this, so that we can figure out [what package has a dependency to an old version of a package that was broken](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/issues/861).

Answer (score 37):

While we're waiting for the official tools to have this functionality, here's the uglyslow vershion:

```
for p in `meteor list | grep '^[a-z]' | awk '{ print $1"@"$2 }'`; do echo "$p"; meteor show "$p" | grep -E '^  [a-z]'; echo; done
```

This will show the dependencies of all added packages. It parses the output of `meteor list` and `meteor show package@version` and will break when anything there changes.

Comment: a slightly improved version of this can be found here https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2853 (abernix's comment on march 1, 2017)

Answer (score 15):

As of Meteor v1.5.2 ([released 2017-09-05](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v152-2017-09-05)) you can now see the full dependency tree like this:

`meteor list --tree`

Here's what the output looks like:

```
$ meteor list --tree

accounts-password@1.4.0
├─┬ accounts-base@1.3.4
│ ├─┬ callback-hook@1.0.10
│ │ └── underscore@1.0.10
│ ├── check@1.2.5 (top level)
│ ├─┬ ddp@1.3.1
│ │ ├─┬ ddp-client@2.1.3
│ │ │ ├── callback-hook@1.0.10 (expanded above)
│ │ │ ├── check@1.2.5 (top level)
│ │ │ ├─┬ ddp-common@1.2.9
```

The pull request was contributed by [sdarnel](https://github.com/sdarnell) and can be found here for those interested:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/8936

Comment: This is the new answer! Thanks Adrian :-)

Comment: Is it possible to print this same tree view, but for ones own files in a Meteor project? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did...

I ran `meteor list`, and copied the output to notepad, to refer back to later.

Then, I went down the entire list, entering: `meteor show <package>` looking in the output for: `Implies: whatever`... that's the part that tells you what the particular package is including. Basically, the part of the output that says "Implies: something", those are the dependencies of the package you ran `meteor show <package>` for.

Then... if you take the packages in "Implies: foopackage", and run "meteor show foopackage" that will tell you *that* dependency's dependencies.

Basically, this is a crude solution to this problem which there is no official solution/feature/command for.

Good luck.

P.S. in my case, I wanted to see what was including `iron:router`, and through the above process, I determined it was `useraccounts:semantic-ui` that was including `useraccounts:core`, which in turn was including `iron:router` (which isn't in `meteor list`!)

See the following page for more info: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2853

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some [code here](https://gist.github.com/deanius/d3f18b07454cd8416417) to build up a package tree, and make pictures like this:

[image]

It worked on the raw source code of the meteor distribution, so it'd need some tweaking to work on an actual app (and I cant help with that at the moment), but it'd be a start...

Comment: Nice looking, but could you also explain succinctly how your code works? That way if for some reason your repo gets hit by a bus the legacy is preserved.